NPS extension for Azure MFA timestamp issue
I'm trying to setup VPN auth via RADIUS using Windows Server NPS and Azure MFA NPS extension.
Here's the error I am getting:
NPS Extension for Azure MFA:  CID: 104def04-3db0-47d6-a82f-8b9249eca19c:
Exception in Authentication Ext for User jlocke:: ErrorCode:: ESTS_TOKEN_ERROR Msg::
Unable to get Azure AD access token. [Reason:AADSTS700024: Client assertion is not within its valid time range.
Current time: 2024-07-02T11:25:42.8683642Z, assertion valid from 2024-07-02T12:23:59.0000000Z, expiry time of assertion 2024-07-02T12:33:59.0000000Z. Review the documentation at https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials . Trace ID: c9813b48-ae40-493a-be53-a3a45eb48f00 Correlation ID: e3dfe056-fbdd-4b4b-8852-2d55991e97be Timestamp: 2024-07-02 11:25:42Z][Code:3399614473] Enter ERROR_CODE @ https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=846827 for detailed troubleshooting steps.
Timestamps:
Current time:           2024-07-02T11:25:42.8683642Z
assertion valid from        2024-07-02T12:23:59.0000000Z
expiry time of assertion    2024-07-02T12:33:59.0000000Z
Actual time on DC server was 1:23:59 PM.
Using health check script I confirmed that RADIUS auth without MFA addon is working fine (it isolates NPS extension by disabling it).
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-mfa-nps-extension-health-check
Integration with Azure AD also seems fine using this script, all tests passed.
Not really sure where to go from there since it seems time is okay - same on both VPN concentrator and AD/RADIUS server.
